# Creating JfreeCharts in a for loop

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jfreechart

I am reading from an input stream and storing data in an array. Now if some test condition(and although the inputstream is not fully read I want to create a chart).

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainArr.size(); i++) 
{ 
     JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonMainArr.getJSONObject(i);   
    String date1 = childJSONObject.getString("date");
    DateFormat forma=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date dre=forma.parse(date1);
    d[i]=dre;

    if(somecondition)
    {
        CandleStickChart chart = new CandleStickChart("Candle Stick Chart");
        chart.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(chart);
        chart.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now if `dre` is a particular data, I want to display the chart. I don't want to break out of the for loop because the other data (the next companies data still needs to be parsed). I have noticed this does not work inside the loop and only works outside it. What can I do to overcome this difficulty.

Comment: Some things need clarification here:  Are you displaying the chart on an awt/swing frame?  What triggers this code to run (Is it a UI event like a click)?  How long do you want to display the graph for?  Do you want the user to acknowledge / close it?

Comment: Currently i am debugging so it is triggered when i run the main with no test condition. I am displaying the graph by extending the application frame and using the setCOntentPane method.

Comment: The `add()` method has "been overridden to forward to the `contentPane` as necessary."—[JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html).

Comment: Im sorry but i dont understand what the above comment means.

Answer (score 2):

Run your data acquisition loop on another thread, such as [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). Invoke `publish()` only for completed models, marking those that you want to display. Display the chart in `process()`.